# How to separate each row of a matrix and put into a group?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix `A`, the size of which is `1500*4000` (`row*column`). My question is how to separate each row of a matrix and put them into a group, since I want to use this command:

```
[group, groupNames] = grp2idx(A);
```

When I run this command, MATLAB gives this error:

> Grouping variable must be a vector or a character array.
>
> ```
> error in :[group, groupNames] = grp2idx(A);
> ```

Comment: Each row of a matrix and put them into a group?  Can't you just put each row into a cell array?  Try doing: `group = arrayfun(@(x) A(x,:), 1:size(A,1), 'uni', false); groupNames = 1:size(A,1);`  Would this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to place each row of a matrix and put them into a group?

Can't you just put each row into a cell array?  Try doing:

```
group = arrayfun(@(x) A(x,:), 1:size(A,1), 'uni', false); 
groupNames = 1:size(A,1);
```

`groupNames` are enumerated from 1 to as many rows as you have, and `group` is a cell array where the i<sup>th</sup> element would contain the i<sup>th</sup> row of your matrix `A`.

Comment: @user3761566 if this is the case please click on the checkmark underneath the up and down arrows beside this post on the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`grd2idx` takes a vector as an input. Read its documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/grp2idx.html). If you want to group each row as on then you can use [mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).

```
grouped_cell = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2));
```

Then to access the group formed by `ith` row you can use `i_group = grouped_cell{i};`

Comment: it does not work. My question is how to apply A to this command:[group, groupNames] = grp2idx(A);

Comment: @user3761566 you cannot apply A to `grp2idx` as `grp2idx` takes vectors instead of matrix as an input. Please provide a minimal example to be more clear of what you want

Comment: I want to do svm 10 fold cross validation. I change to this:load A; groups = ismember(A,'setosa');cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold',groups,k); It also show the same erro

Answer (score 2):

As Nishant said, you need to convert your matrix into a vector,

You could do this to convert your matrix into a vector:

```
B = A(:).
```

Then use B instead of A.

```
[group, groupNames] = grp2idx(B);
```

Now you should not have the error.

Comment: Write how you could use `B` instead of `A` for `grp2idx` for self-containment.  We should not have to look at other people's posts to understand this code.

Comment: when I use this:svmModel = svmtrain(meas(trainIdx,:),group(trainIdx),'Autoscale',true,... the error shows: "undefined variable meas" How to fix this problem?

Comment: @user3761566 - ... read what the error message says.  `Undefined variable meas`.  That means `meas` is **NOT** declared in your code.  MATLAB error messages are pretty verbose.  They pretty much explain exactly what is wrong with your code.

Comment: @lakesh - No worries!  Just wanted to make sure :)  Good answer btw. +1.